# Unexpected "ImportError"

Tags: python

For some reason, in my python script, I am getting an unexpected ImportError.

After doing a bit of research, I found that the most common cause of this issue is the existence of circular inheritance. However, I do not think that this error applies in this case.

I have two classes, app.py and Face_Detector.py.

Imports for app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from Face_Detector import Face_Detector, detect_face
```

Imports for Face_Detector.py:

```
import io
import os
import json

from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
```

For some reason, I keep getting an error stating

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'detect_face'
```

Comment: Have you tried from Face_Detector import *

Comment: We need to see the code from  Face_Detector.py

Comment: I don't see a definition of `detect_face` in `Face_Detector.py`.

Comment: @m1009ct0 doing this solved the problem.

Comment: @EagleBeagle can you +1 the comment please.

Comment: @m1009ct0 there are no upvote or downvote arrows next to your comment. There is only one next to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to import all of it. By using * (asterisk)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from Face_Detector import *
```